# facebook Error b is null

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a fanpage on facebook, when the page loads I m getting error because of  FB.getLoginStatus.

```
b is null [Break On This Error] FB.provide('',{ui:function(f,b){f=FB.c...onent(FB.UIServer._resultToken));}});

b is null
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
Line 22
```

all.js FB.provide('',{ui:function(f,b){f=FB.copy({}.....

I'm really confused why I'm getting b is null, check my current code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title><?php echo APP_NAME; ?></title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
      appId   : 'xxxxxxx',
      status  : true, // check login status
      cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml   : true
    });
    //FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b){FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b; }
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

      if (!response.session) {
          FB.login(friendsGet);
      } 
      else 
      {
          friendsGet(response);
      }
    });

};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol 
        + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

thanks

Comment: It's strange, I'm not getting this error [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4XJUp/3/). Additionally, you shouldn't use FBML as it's deprecated

Comment: it  get error here, when it come on this function FB.login

Comment: I got this error because the authentication popup was blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the error as well and as ElbertF writes, it's because the browser blocks the pop up window.

Only way to get over this is to let the user do an action and then call FB.Login. Let him click something - anything.

Why is facebook even using popups?? Totally old school.

/Rune